# SSIS Excel Destination Create Worksheet Work with Variables?

Tags: ssis, ssis-2016

When I hit the "new" button, it starts a create table statement. Is there a way to replace the default table name with a variable?

Comment: Try to use the variable in the target connectionstring property. I have used variables to change the source side successfully. Haven't tested the target.

Comment: I don't see where that is, can you tell me?

Comment: I see it, but I don't think I will be able to do this.